The Python Azure Function is executed twice
I have a telegram bot in which there is a /start command.
In this command it is checked whether a person was previously registered (he had previously switched to a bot) or not, if there was, it displays a warning to him, and if not, it displays a welcome message accordingly.
Everything worked fine on my laptop. But when I made a deploy in Azure Function HTTP Trigger, I noticed that when a person writes /start for the first time, he gets a single message that he has already been registered, although he should have gotten a welcome message.
What is this problem related to?
I think there are no problems with the code, since everything works fine on my laptop.

Can you please provide some more details, and some code?
